# Can't get a CALayer to update its drawLayer: DURING a bounds animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm trying to animate a custom UIView's bounds while also keeping its layer the same size as its parent view. To do that, I'm trying to animate the layers bounds alongside its parent view. I need the layer to call drawLayer:withContext AS its animating so my custom drawing will change size correctly along with the bounds.

drawLayer is called correctly and draws correctly before I start the animation. But I can't get the layer to call its drawLayer method on EACH step of the bounds animation. Instead, it just calls it ONCE, jumping immediately to the "end bounds" at the final frame of the animation.

```
// self.bg is a property pointing to my custom UIView
self.bg.layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
self.bg.layer.mask.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;

[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{

    [CATransaction begin];
    self.bg.layer.bounds = bounds;
    self.bg.layer.mask.bounds = bounds;
    [CATransaction commit];

    self.bg.bounds = bounds;
} completion:nil];
```

Why doesn't the bounds report a change AS its animating (not just the final frame)? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might or might not help...

Many people are unaware that Core Animation has a supercool feature that allows you to define your own layer properties in such a way that they can be animated. An example I use is to give a CALayer subclass a `thickness` property. When I animate it with Core Animation...

```
CABasicAnimation* ba = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"thickness"];
ba.toValue = @10.0f;
ba.autoreverses = YES;
[lay addAnimation:ba forKey:nil];
```

...the effect is that `drawInContext:` or `drawLayer:...` is called repeatedly throughout the animation, allowing me to change repeatedly the way the layer is drawn in accordance with its *current* `thickness` property value at each moment (an intermediate value in the course of the animation).

It seems to me that that *might* be the sort of thing you're after. If so, you can find a working downloadable example here:

https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/ch17p498customAnimatableProperty

Discussion (from my book) here:

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_making_a_property_animatable

Comment: `is called repeatedly throughout the animation` Not automatically, it isn't. It's a good solution, but the drawback is that you need to impliment `needsDisplayForKey:` and to do that you need to subclass CALayer. And since there are a number of CALayer subclasses that you might need to use (like CAGradientLayer, etc) it can be a bit of a pain in the butt.

Comment: Since presentationLayer only returns a static copy, I matt's answer is the only thing that works for now. I guess I'll have to add special custom properties for width and height and animate them alongside bounds. Does that sound correct?

Comment: I can't be *certain* it will work the way you want, but that is certainly the direction I was thinking you should be going in when I made this suggestion.

Comment: Your answer is more that a "supercool feature". I'm pretty sure it's the only non-hacky way to trigger a "bounds change event" during animation. Remember that only the values on the PRESENTATION LAYER change DURING animation, and the presentationLayer property is static and read-only, so it can't be observed.

Comment: My solution (very similar to your answer) is to animate 2 custom CGFloat properties, boundsWidth and boundsHeight, in a CAAnimationGroup alongside the bounds animation. Those 2 custom properties trigger setNeedsDisplay via `needsDisplayForKey`. Does that sound correct to you?

Comment: All I can tell you is that it is just the kind of thing I was thinking of. Needn't be two properties, perhaps, but that might not matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the layer you are drawing to is not the same layer as the one displayed on the screen.

When you animate a layer property it will immediately be set to its final value in the model layer, (as you have noticed), and the actual animation is done in the presentation layer.

You can access the presentation layer and see the actual values of the animated properties:

```
CALayer *presentationLayer = (CALayer *)[self.bg.layer presentationLayer];
...
```

Since you haven't provided your `drawLayer:withContext` method, it's unclear what you want to draw during the animation, but if you want to animate custom properties, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.nomadplanet.fr/2010/11/animate-calayer-custom-properties-with-coreanimation/) for doing that.

Comment: Wow I didn't know about presentationLayer. Thank you for that. In my drawLayer, I just have a UIBezierPath with a few addArcWithCenter methods. I could add it here, but I honestly don't think it has any sort of effect on whether or not drawLayer is called.

Comment: Can I use the presentationLayer to trigger drawLayer:? According to the docs, the presentationLayer methods returns a copy of the presentationLayer, so I'm not sure if observing the bounds property is possible...

Comment: Yes, it returns a copy of the presentation layer, it is only for reading. I don't think your drawLayer method will be called during the animation, unless you go with something like matts answer. That's why I asked what you had in that method, to see if it was animateable.

Comment: Its not animateable...that's why I need drawLayer: to be called on every frame of the animation. Anyway, you still have a very good answer. Wish I could give more than one upvote.

Comment: you're right...a much better approach is animating the bezier path of a layer, not redrawing the whole layer on every animation frame.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the layer of a layer backed (or hosting) view is always resized to fit the bounds of its parent view. If you set the view to be the layers delegate then the view will receive drawLayer:inContext: at each frame. Of course you must ensure that If your layer has `needsDisplayOnBoundsChange == YES`.

Here is an example (on the Mac) of resizing a window, which then changes the path of the underlying layer.

```
// My Nib contains one view and one button. 
// The view has a MPView class and the button action is resizeWindow:

@interface MPView() {
    CAShapeLayer     *_hostLayer;
    CALayer          *_outerLayer;
    CAShapeLayer     *_innerLayer;
}
@end

@implementation MPView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

    _hostLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    _hostLayer.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor].CGColor;
    _hostLayer.borderColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
    _hostLayer.borderWidth = 2;
    _hostLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
    _hostLayer.delegate = self;
    _hostLayer.lineWidth = 4;
    _hostLayer.strokeColor = [NSColor greenColor].CGColor;
    _hostLayer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;

    self.layer = _hostLayer;
    self.wantsLayer = YES;

    [CATransaction commit];

    [self.window setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200) display:YES animate:NO];
}

- (void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    if (layer == _hostLayer) {

        CGSize size = layer.bounds.size;
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, size.width, size.height);

        _hostLayer.path = path;

        CGPathRelease(path);
    }
}

- (IBAction)resizeWindow:(id)sender
{
    [self.window setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 1200, 800) display:YES animate:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Isn't the views layer set as its delegate by default? Or do I have to do this in the views init:  `self.layer.delegate = self;`

Comment: By default the delegate is nil so you must set it yourself.

Comment: @yourfriendzak Only the default layer. I believe it actually throws an exception if its delegate is not its view.

Comment: I tried putting `NSLog(@"layer delegate: %@",self.layer.delegate);` in the view's `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` and it was set to the view without me adding it. Maybe something behind the scenes is setting it.

Comment: Then I think @Sulthan is correct that for layer backed views (as opposed to layer hosting) it is set to the view automatically. I was unaware of that.

Comment: @aLevelOfIndirection Actually, on iOS, `[UIView layer]` is readonly. You can change it using `+[UIView layerClass]` (e.g. OpenGL apps do that) but usually it's easier to just add another layer over the default layer.